# Nested resources to two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have 3 models: Account, Organization and Person

```
Account 
  has many Organizations 
  has many People
Organization
  belongs to Account
  has many People
People
  belongs to Organization
  belongs to Account
```

The problem here is, when creating a new Account, Organization and Person in the same form, how to write the account_id and the organization_id to the people table?

Comment: Please provide the form structure, the controller action code currently in use and any other details (like if you use accepts_nested_attributes_for) etc

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your models like this:

**app/models/account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :organizations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end
```

**app/models/organization.rb**

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :people
end
```

Then you will set up the `new` action in your `AccountsController` like this:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @account = Account.new
    organization = @account.organizations.build
    person = @account.people.build
  end
end
```

Why? Well, because you'll set up the form in `app/views/accounts/new.html.erb` like this:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |account| %>
  <%# account fields go here, like this: %>
  <p>
    <%= account.label :name %>
    <%= account.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <%# then organization fields, nested inside the account (which is what account represents) %>
  <%# this will create a new set of fields for each organization linked to the account %>

  <%= account.fields_for :organizations do |organization| %>
    <p>
      <%= account.label :name %>
      <%= account.text_field :name %>
    </p>

    <%# and finally, people %>
    <%= organization.fields_for :people do |person| %>
      <p>
        <%= person.label :name %>
        <%= account.text_field :name %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

These fields will then all be passed back to the `create` action in `AccountsController` nested inside `params[:account]`. You deal with them like this:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])
    if @account.save
      # do something here like...
      redirect_to root_path, :notice => "Account created!"
    else
      #
      flash[:error] = "Account creation failed!"
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Because you've defined `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in both the `Account` and `Organization` models, the params will be parsed successfully and when it creates the account it will create the organization and link it to the account, and then create the person and link it to the organization also.

Done!

Comment: Hi Ryan! hay isn't accepts_nested_attributes_for a security concern here since it's probably a public form, and it's over a has_many relation (that can be engineering to submit too many children) ? I'd rather have 3 separate hashes, add :inverse_of to relations, build on lase 2 relations and save.

Comment: You can have a check in the controller if that worries you. If you build an idiot proof system...

Comment: I did that: http://pastie.org/3010947 and I get error "Organizations people account can't be blank" and "Organizations people organization can't be blank", since I validated the account_id and organization_id for presence

Comment: You know, that works, but when I validate the organization_id on People model, I get validation error. Whyyy?! without the validation, it works fine and does add the organization_id